# Change Folder Permissions with Terminal

Tags: permissions, terminal, directory, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to change the permissions of a folder. I want to make a folder, and **everything** in it restricted to me only; other users can't view it.

The folder, though, contains hundreds of other files in it. Is there a way in Terminal to change the permissions a folder *and everything in it*? I know this can be accomplished with "Get info" but there's simply too much files inside that folder to manually do that with every file.

I'm running on OS X Mavericks 10.9.5.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you try chmod -R (recursive)

Answer (score 1):

of course there is a way.

You should set the ownership to your user and remove at least the executable flag for the folder. No one will be able to enter the folder via the cd command or the finder, etc.

First change directory to the location where the desired folder is located (its parent folder).

```
cd path/to/parent/folder
```

then remove the executable flag for its group (g) and all others (o)

```
chmod go-x folder
```

If you also want to make its contents invisible for actions like

```
ls folder/
```

then you have to remove the readable flag also.

```
chmod go-r folder
```

@micebrain: And there is no need for changing the permissions recursively for all folders and files inside the folder, because you can control the access of opening a folder.

BTW the executable bit (x) - if set - makes files executable and folders openable...

Comment: I tried doing "cd Documents/Maze" which worked. Then I tried "chmod go-x folder" which resulted in _chmod: folder: No such file or directory_. By the way, the parent folder is called "Maze" and it's basically a folder with folders inside it with more folders inside it, like a maze.

Comment: Okay. Just cd into you Documents directory.

The word **folder** was meant to be replaced by your foldername.
So run `cd ~/Documents` followed by `chmod go-x Maze` and `chmod go-r Maze`

Comment: I did exactly that, but when I looked inside one of the subfolders it still said "Everyone: Read only." I want to make the whole folder and all its subfolders inaccessible. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you paste the output, that comes out when you do ls -l in the parent folder?

Comment: Because you removed the executable bit of the Maze folder for "everyone" except you (chmod go-x Maze), no one except you will be able to open the folder, and see its contents (even if the files/folders inside show "everyone: read only." At least that was what I tested, before answering your question. Another option is `chmod -R go-rwx Maze` This removes read, write and execution rights for everyone except your current user recursively for all files inside Maze...

Comment: Hmm. I tried going into one of the subfolders as Guest User after doing "cd Documents" and then "chmod -R go-rwx Maze." Well, thanks for your help anyways.